# Regex matching doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match every string (url) starting with "string" and not ending in -[number]

So I made this regex

```
string/?.*(?!-[0-9]*)
```

which, for what I understood, is supposed to be read as:

> match every string starting with "string", having possibly a '/' after
>   it, having any string after it not including '-' followed by any
>   number or numbers.

here's my test strings

```
string/kkk/aaa/sss/ddd-123
string/kkk/aaa/sss/ddd
string/kkk/aaa/sss
string/kkk/aaa
string/kkk
string/
string/kkk/
string/kkk/aaa/
string/74002
```

the regex just match everything, no matter what.

Could someone tell me where I went wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your expression you have added `.*` at the before the lookahead.

This means `*` will skip all available characters matching `.` before proceeding to the next step - This in essence is everything and hence your expression matches everything.  This is usually used when you want to return everything after a pattern.

You need to move the `.*` in to the lookahead statement or use a non-greedy version.

Try something like

```
^string/?(?!.+?-\d+$).*
```

The above will match all string that do not end with `-` and digits.  It will also return the entire string for instances where the pattern is matched.  I have used the non-greedy `.+?` here to avoid confusion as well as adding the `^` start and `$` end of line selectors.  The `.*` matches all the characters if the pattern is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str  = "string/kkk/aaa/sss/ddd123";
echo preg_match("/^string\/(?!.*-\d+$)/",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you don't force the regular expression to match the whole string.

For example, take this line:

```
string/kkk/aaa/sss/ddd-123
```

In this case `.*` will simply match everything after `string/` including the `-123`. A non-greedy match would match everything excluding the `d-123`. In either case it succeeds in not finding what's given in the negative lookahead.

You'll have to force the regular expression to match the string end (`$`) (and probably the string start (`^`) as well:

```
^string/?.*(?!-[0-9]*)$
```